# Which partial orders can be extended to a copy of $\omega$?

Tags: logic, order-theory

It is a well-known result of ZFC that every partial order $\preccurlyeq$ can be extended to a total one (by adding pairs to $\preccurlyeq$), and similarly, that every well-founded partial order can be extended to a well-order.

I was wondering what conditions are needed on the partial order to guarantee it has a linear extension with order type $\omega$. Among infinite total orders, $\omega$ seems to be unique with the property
$$\begin{equation}
    \text{every element has finitely many others below it}\tag{$*$}
\end{equation}$$

In particular, $(*)$ implies well-foundedness, as well as no maximal element (for infinite orders). I'm not sure if this condition has a name, or has been studied before.

Now, **is is true that any countably infinite partial order satisfying $(*)$ can be extended to a total order isomorphic to $\omega$?** If not, is there another known (necessary and) sufficient condition?

Comment: There are uncountable partial orders satisfying your condition (eg an uncountable discrete set). And there are also finite partial orders satisfying your condition, of course! So you should add the hypothesis that the poset is countably infinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes: if $X$ is a countably infinite set and $\trianglelefteq$ is a partial order on $X$ such that $\{y\in X:y\trianglelefteq x\}$ is finite for each $x\in X$, then there is a total ordering $\trianglelefteq'$ on $X$ such that $\trianglelefteq\subseteq\trianglelefteq'$ and $(X,\trianglelefteq')\cong(\omega,<)$.

To see this, let $X,\trianglelefteq$ be as above and fix some enumeration $(x_i)_{i\in\omega}$ of $X$. We recursively build a sequence of elements of $X$ as follows. At stage $s$, having defined $y_t$ for all $t<s$, let $i$ be the least natural number such that $x_i\not\in\{y_t:t<s\}$ but $\{x\in X: x\triangleleft x_i\}\subseteq\{y_t:t<s\}$. We then let $y_s=x_i$.

It's easy to check that $(y_i)_{i\in\omega}$ gives a new enumeration of $X$, the key point being that the finite downward cone condition means that every element of $X$ eventually "becomes available." We now turn this into an ordering of $X$ of ordertype $\omega$ in the obvious way: letting $f:\omega\rightarrow\omega$ be the "reindexing" function $x_i=y_{f(i)}$, we set $$x_i\trianglelefteq'x_j\iff f(i)<f(j).$$

---

More generally, the same argument shows:

> Let $\kappa$ be any infinite cardinal, and suppose $(X,\trianglelefteq)$ is a well-founded partial order such that $\vert X\vert=\kappa$ and $\vert\{y\in X: y\trianglelefteq x\}\vert<\kappa$ for each $x\in X$. Then there is a $\trianglelefteq'\subseteq X^2$ such that $\trianglelefteq\subseteq\trianglelefteq'$ and $(X,\trianglelefteq')\cong(\kappa,<)$.

Comment: Do you happen to know if the more general statement (or even the specific statement you proved) appears in the literature somewhere?  I recently proved essentially this same lemma in a paper I am writing and in the process of looking for a reference, I came across this post.

Comment: @LouisD I don't know offhand, but I would look at the literature around [Szpilrajn's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szpilrajn_extension_theorem). The lemma is really just a natural extension (pun intended) ofSzpilrajn's argument.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I did begin by looking at that literature, but I never found this specific statement.  Perhaps I will just give the argument in my paper and make reference to the fact that this is a natural extension of Szpilrajn's theorem (so the statement itself may well just be folklore).

Comment: I finally did find a reference in the literature.  This statement can be found in Theory of Relations (revised edition) by Fra\"iss'e in Section 2.15.1.  I should also point out that the proof that you give above (and my proof that I made reference to) only works for regular cardinals.  After spending some time with a colleague coming up with a proof for the singular case, I finally stumbled across the thing I was originally looking for.  One possibly interesting question which I still have is whether there is a unified proof which works in both the regular and singular case.